# How do I iterate through a set of element that were added dynamically after DOM init?

Tags: jquery, dom, dynamically-generated

An Ajax call returns a set of html table rows that are added to an empty table.

Each row has an X (remove) button.

After having the rows added I need to loop through the rows and assign a 'click' event for each X button to call a function that will remove its parent row.

Apparently $('.myrows').each() doesn't work as the rows are added after DOM init.

How do I go about this?

Thanks!!

Comment: You should add some code to show the effort.

Answer (score -1):

try using

`$('id/class of parent div').find('.myrows').each(function (i,r) {});`